# Python - Multiprocessing - Logging each process indepently

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using Python 3 multiprocessing.pool and apply_async.

Inside each process I get a logger and log to a different file each time. But what I see is that the log file contains all the log entries of all the processes.

Is it possible to have each process log to it's own file only the entries logged within the process?

This is an example code that reproduces the problem:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import ApplyResult


def test(index):
    import logging

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    filename = '{}.log'.format(str(index))
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    logger.debug(str(index))    
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = []
    pool = Pool(processes=1)

    for i in range(10):
        apply_async = pool.apply_async(test, args=(i,))
        results.append(apply_async)

    map(ApplyResult.wait, results)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The first log generated is **0.log**:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

**1.log**:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

etc.

Comment: Of course it is. For example in each process define log files based on `os.getpid()`.

Comment: The issue is not creating a different file for each process. The issue is that the files generated contains the log entries of the other processes

Comment: That's... weird. Show us the code, please.

Comment: @freakish I added an example code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a specific name in the getLogger method?

```
logger = logging.getLogger(str(index))
```

Otherwise the logging module will default to the root logger. This might explain why each n process captures n to 9.